# asp.net mvc 4 routing for short url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I want my product display url should look like

```
http://example.com/Black-TShirt
```

but presently what i am getting is like url

```
http://example.com/controller/actionname/2/Black-TShirt
```

how should i write the following code ?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "productview",
                url: "{controller}/{actionname}/{id}/{productname}",
                defaults: new { controller = "product", action = "display", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: do you need the product id in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need `productname` to be the only one parameter to be provided in the url! See following code

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "productview",
            url: "{productname}",
            defaults: new { controller = "product", action = "display"} 
        );
```

And your controller action must be (something like)

```
  public ActionResult Display(string productname){
        var product=Service.GetProductByName(productname);
       return View(product);
  }
```

Note that I use `action` not `actionname` for route